# cartoon or anime where there was a kid with a magic stone that could summon a magical creature

Tags: story-identification, tv, animated-series

in Canada, I don't remember specifics but what I remember was that the show had a boy that could summon a magical creature from a stone and I think I watched it before 2010. It was in English and I think it may have been 2008 or close to when I first saw it. Also I think the creature was some kind of tiger or elephant like thing, I don't entirely remember. Cant remember what the boy looked like though. The boy was young though. the stone also was about the size of his hand and had a symbol of some kind, he could also get more than 1. the style of the show was also a bit old. The only two things I remember is near the beginning he is in a jungle or forest and later in a snowy rock area.

Comment: Please visit https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question and see if you can [edit] more details in. Like was the boy Caucasian? Asian? Greenskinned? What kind of creature was it? Animal-like? Genie? Demon? Elemental? Were there others who can summon magical creatures from stones?

Comment: If you don't add more details, odds are this is going to be closed. :(

Comment: Glad I could help. Your question has been closed as a Duplicate, but that's not a bad thing. You can still get upvotes on the question. This just links your question to previous times it has been answered.

Comment: We actually get a lot of people asking about this series, so you're in good company.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the additional details, that sounds like it could be *[Magi-Nation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magi-Nation_(TV_series))* as per [Anime with gems that can summon beasts to fight for the user, one is a purple turtle](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/144597/anime-with-gems-that-can-summon-beasts-to-fight-for-the-user-one-is-a-purple-tu?rq=1).

[image: Title image of Magi-Nation]

> Three thousand years ago in the Moonlands, the evil Shadow Magi Agram was sealed inside the planet's Core by the Core Glyph and the Dreamstones which provided its power. Now he plans to escape by using his Shadow Geysers to weaken his prison in order to bring the Moonlands under his control, and only a Magi known as the "Final Dreamer" can stop him. A young boy from Earth, Tony Jones, is summoned into the Moonlands as he is believed to be this Final Dreamer. He joins forces with the apprentice Magi, Edyn, and the Shadow Stalker, Strag, on a mission to gather the Dreamstones before Agram is set free. Using the Book of Elders, the three travel through the Moonlands while combatting the forces of Agram and gaining an ever-growing collection of Dream Creatures from the Moonlands that they visit.

As you can see in the image, Tony's creature, Furok, does look somewhat tiger-like.

One thing that does not match is that the [animite](https://magination.fandom.com/wiki/Animite) crystals they use to summon the Dream Creatures just look like crystals:

[image: Tony, Edyn, and Strag hold up their animite crystals]

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go out on a limb and say this will probably wind up being *[Huntik: Secrets and Seekers](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1696969/)* as per [Animated show with character who has a stone that summons creatures](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/186121/animated-show-with-character-who-has-a-stone-that-summons-creatures).

[image: Title image of Huntik]

> Lok and Sophie happen upon a journal left by Lok's father. The Organization, a group of evil Seekers, is after the book, and to survive they must join a group of good Seekers under master adventurer Dante and lone wolf Zhalia.

It's an amulet he uses, but it does look a bit like a stone.

[image: Deviantart depictions of amulets in the series]

Comment: this is close i think ill add more details i just rememberd from this