# Animated TV show where a boy summons a forbidden monster. His friends (a boy and a girl) can also summon creatures

Tags: story-identification, tv, animated-series

As a kid (2010-2014) I remember watching this animated TV show on Netflix(?) in the US.

The show was about this kid who is the main character. He has black hair (I think) and summons some sort of fire bull-like creature from a book. I am pretty sure that he was not supposed to summon it, because I think it was forbidden.

There was also a blonde girl who can summon dark creatures and another boy who I think has black (or brown) hair and can summon bug-like creatures.

At one point some light master betrays them.

Comment: Welcome to Scifi, please add some detail according to our [checklist](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2041/checklist-for-story-identification).

Comment: Huntik? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/186121/animated-show-with-character-who-has-a-stone-that-summons-creatures

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like ***[Kaijudo: Rise of the Duel Masters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaijudo)*** (2012-2013).

> *Kaijudo* is a 2012 American animated series and trading card game that serve as a spin-off and relaunch of the Japanese Duel Masters franchise. The animated series was produced by Hasbro Studios, animated by Moi Animation in South Korea, and developed by Henry Gilroy and Andrew R. Robinson for Wizards of the Coast.

> The series follows the adventures of a young boy named Ray Okamoto from San Campion who possesses the rare ability to summon and duel alongside fantastical creatures from a parallel dimension. Ray and his two best friends Allie and Gabe join the ranks of the mysterious Duel Masters to ensure the survival of both races.

The main character, [Ray](https://kaijudo.fandom.com/wiki/Raiden_Pierce-Okamoto), has mostly-black hair, and can summon a creature called [Tatsurion the Unchained](https://kaijudo.fandom.com/wiki/Tatsurion_the_Unchained_(Character)), a quadrupedal fire beast with horns and a tail. There's also a blonde girl, [Allie](https://kaijudo.fandom.com/wiki/Allison_Underhill), and another boy, [Gabe](https://kaijudo.fandom.com/wiki/Gabriel_Wallace), who can summon creatures of their own.

[image: Image of the three main characters from Kaijudo: Rise of the Duel Masters.]

The light master you referred to might be [Master Nigel Brightmore](https://kaijudo.fandom.com/wiki/Nigel_Brightmore), a former [Duel Master](https://kaijudo.fandom.com/wiki/Duel_Master) himself, and "an expert on the Light Civilization and its creatures," who ended up siding with [The Choten](https://kaijudo.fandom.com/wiki/The_Choten), another former Duel Master, and the chief antagonist of the series.

Comment: Yes that I am pretty sure is it thank very much