# Fantasy cartoon show aired in India around 2005-12; main character searches for his father. Involved magic rings

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

It's a fantasy cartoon show which was aired in India around 2005-12.

This show is about a man who was trying to find his dad, and he has his dad's diary containing information about some magic or monster. During his search, he meets guys who also know the info written in the diary. The main character and others find magical rings, also lots more.

Comment: Hi there! :) I've taken the liberty to rephrase that a bit, feel free to rollback if you think it changes the meaning of your question. Also, you could take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) on how to write a good story-ID question to see if that triggers some more memories :)

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/205076/anime-with-a-boy-hiring-a-creature-from-a-stone-meets-a-man-named-dante-and-sta (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 7):

Maybe *Huntik* (2009-2012)?

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huntik:_Secrets_%26_Seekers#Broadcast),

> In India, the series' first season aired on Disney XD (India) in 2010.

[image: Huntik still; two teenage girls, one teenage blond boy, one red-haired adult]

There's Lok, the blonde guy who discovered his father's amulet. While studying with a friend, it is revealed that his father, who was missing, may be alive. Lok and his friend go on a quest to find him, based on hints in the father's journal (see picture below).

[image: A cartoon diary]

There are creatures known as the Titans, and they're summoned by amulets. Below is a collection of Titans and their amulets.

[image: Full Titans sheet]

Throughout the series, the kids fight against the evil Organization, whose goal is to rule over the world (such originality !). The Organization seeks a huge, legendary-like Titan to ensure their doomination. So basically, they're like villainous Pokémon teams, but without the catchy name.

Comment: By the way, if this answer feels familiar to anyone, it's because I added some elements to [my answer to another question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/186121/what-cartoon-animated-show-is-this/186124#186124) to match the details given by OP. The question is possibly a dupe then.