# An anime with necklaces with crystals to summon monsters

Tags: story-identification, anime

I watched an anime around 2008-2010. In it, the main characters use crystals to summon monsters to fight.

All I can remember is the main characters' appearances:

- one was a red hair male middle age
- one teen blond guy
- one teen girl

Comment: possible dupe of [Anime with gems that can summon beasts to fight for the user, one is a purple turtle](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/144597/anime-with-gems-that-can-summon-beasts-to-fight-for-the-user-one-is-a-purple-tu)

Comment: it is not the magi thing

Answer (score 5):

Probably [*Huntik*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1696969/), an American-Italian cartoon aired between 2009 and 2012.

[image: Cartoon still]

- The blonde guy, Lok, goes to school in Italy;
- Sophie (the skirt girl) is a student from the same school;
- The middle-aged, red-haired guy is Dante, one of the Seekers; Seekers can summon creatures known as the Titans, and Dante particularly can summon Caliban, as he does in the first episode (see video below);
- the second teen girl (dark-haired one on the right) is called Zhalia, she joins them later in the series.

Here's a sheet with all Titans and their summoning amulets:

[image: Titans sheet]

Throughout the series, the kids fight against the evil Organization, whose goal is to rule over the world (such originality !). The Organization seeks a huge, legendary-like Titan to ensure their domination. So basically, they're like villainous Pokémon teams, but without the catchy name.

---

Plagiarising my own answers to [Animated show with character who has a stone that summons creatures](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/186121/98028) and [Fantasy cartoon show aired in India around 2005-12; main character searches for his father. Involved magic rings](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/188464/98028)

Comment: ty so much for anwsering so fast it is huntik you can mark this as closed if you'd like

Answer (score 2):

Could it be [*Shin Shirayuki-hime Densetsu Prétear*](https://myanimelist.net/anime/100/Shin_Shirayuki-hime_Densetsu_Pr%C3%A9tear)? I believe it involves using crystals in battles with monsters.

[image: An image of two people, apparently the main characters of the anime]

Comment: it is not pretear :/ like i said in the post how the main characters look but thnx for trying to help