# What is this cartoon with a necklace summoning a monster

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

So I was about eight years old watching a show about a boy with blonde hair. I think he broke a vase and inside was a necklace that summoned a monster. He later on meets 3 other people.

Comment: Welcome to SFF! When you say "eight years old", what year would that be? Please [read our guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and add any details that come to mind. The more details you can add, the more likely you are to get an answer.

Comment: I'm just going off [the answer to another question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/197431/25746) but could this be *Huntik*? The main character's a blonde teenager and the scene with the vase and the necklace happens a few minutes into [the first episode](https://youtu.be/zS4fZMC1qkI?t=261).

Comment: @Withad: That's what I jumped to on seeing the title too. Do you want to post that as an answer?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - Sure, I'll do that now.

Comment: @gaming beast: You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the answer, as per the [tour].

Comment: Seems like "close as dupe" would be a better option, but I'm not a regular here...

Answer (score 1):

Could this be [Huntik: Secrets & Seekers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huntik:_Secrets_%26_Seekers)? It aired from 2009 to around 2013 and focused on a group of magic users who could summon monsters called Titans. The main character is a blonde teenager named [Lok Lambert](https://huntik.fandom.com/wiki/Lok_Lambert):

[image: Lok Lambert, generic protagonist boy of Huntik]

The other main characters are [Sophie Casterwill](https://huntik.fandom.com/wiki/Sophie_Casterwill), [Dante Vale](https://huntik.fandom.com/wiki/Dante_Vale), and [Zhalia Moon](https://huntik.fandom.com/wiki/Zhalia_Moon), who may be the three people you remember him meeting up with.

Finally, the scene you describe with the vase and the necklace happens at [around 4:25 into the first episode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zS4fZMC1qkI&t=261s), where Sophie reaches for the vase and Lok tries to stop her by tackling her for some reason.